# List all webbrowsers installed on OSX, linux or Windows with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I would like to get the list of all webbrowsers installed using nodejs.
If possible on different OS like Windows,OSX and Linux.

For example, if Chrome is installed, I want to run it otherwise run Firefox or IE or Safari depending on the OS.

I can't find any module or internal function to get the webbrowsers.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js works fine.

Comment: It seems to detect only opened browsers. I need to detect browsers before running it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible because you are then saying you would be controlling a user's computer and what software it runs. If you are able to do that, then anyone could.

This assumes you are talking about general usage and not those in a closed and controlled environment, such as a group of users inside a company.

Answer (score 0):

[browser-launcher](https://github.com/james-proxy/james-browser-launcher) enable you to Detect, launch and stop browsers cross platform